# double dot-slash not recognized in command prompt - running npm command

Tags: node.js, window

I have the following in my lerna project package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "../../node_modules/.bin/tsc"
  }
}
```

When running this on a Windows bash.exe, I get

```
'..' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-package@1.0.0 build: `../../node_modules/.bin/tsc`
```

I tried: `"build": "\"../../node_modules/.bin/tsc\""` with no luck. I want this command to work on both Windows and Mac. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I use Git Bash on Windows and the issue cropped up one day when I ran one of my npm scripts. By default on Windows, npm runs scripts using cmd.exe and which doesn't understand dot-slash notation.

The solution for me was to set `npm` to run scripts in `bash`.

For 64-bit:

```bash
npm config set script-shell "C:\\Program Files\\git\\bin\\bash.exe"
```

For 32-bit:

```bash
npm config set script-shell "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\git\\bin\\bash.exe"
```

Alternatively, I believe the git for windows installer lets you add unix capabilities to command prompt, but I didn't test this as the `npm config set` command worked for my needs.